# Filter model by relationship

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Filtering a model by one of it's normal properties is quite simple and I got it working:

```
filteredModel: function() {
    return this.get("model").filterBy("property", filter);
}.property("model")
```

But now my question, how can I filter that model by a hasMany relationship?
My models (which are videos) have 'tags' and I want, for example, just to display videos with the tag 'drawn'.

How could I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include the following in your `ArrayController`:

```
filtered: function() {
  return this.get('content').filter(function(item, index, enumerable){
    var result = false;
    item.get('tags').forEach( function(tag) {
        if (tag.get('name') === 'drawn') result = true;
    });
    return result;
  });
}.property('content.@each')
```

Comment: Yeah, but the problem is that the tags are a `hasMany` relationship in the model. So how can I filter by a relationship in a computed proerty? `this.get('model').filterBy('tags.name', 'drawn');` or similar tricks don't seem to work.